# Get Refresh Token Outlook REST API OAuth PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, oauth, outlook

I completed the PHP tutorial https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/php
Finished the whole Rest API documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/contacts-rest-operations
Have everything working but connection is lost after 60 minutes.
I need a refresh token to get a new access token. But i have never received a refresh token and can't get it. 
Looked over the internet for general OAuth documentation and questions of this forum.

Tried all kind of solutions, nothing works.

```
    $token_request_data = array(
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
        'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => true,
        'refresh_token_lifetime'         => 2419200,
        'approval_prompt'=>'force',
        'access_type'=>'offline',
        'prompt'=>'consent',
        'approval_prompt'=>'force',
        "code" => $authCode,
        "redirect_uri" => self::$redirectUri,
        "scope" => implode(" ", self::$scopes),
        "client_id" => self::$clientId,
        "client_secret" => self::$clientSecret
    );
```

It is told that the refresh token is only send after first sign up for the app.

So I created a complete new app and signed in. But no refresh token in the replied JSON data.

It seems impossible to get a refresh token.

Does anyone succeeded in doing so? How?

Answer (score 2):

With the sandbox https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net i discoverd the answer

In the request thay use

scope=openid+offline_access+

so add offline_access to your scope and the refresh_token is send

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! I can't believe the horrible documentation for this. Here is how I built my url. I needed to be able to send emails via the user. Still working on trying to get the user's email...

```
return USER_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_URL
    + "?client_id=" + config.getClientId()
    + "&redirect_uri=" + getOutlookLoginRedirect(request)
    + "&response_type=code"
    + "&scope=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2Fmail.send offline_access openid"
    + "&state=" + crypto.generateSignedToken();
```